# Android cards multiple layouts based on position

Tags: android, adapter, android-cardview

I want to use different layouts based on card position on screen. For example I need that first card (position 0 uses layout `first_card.xml`) and other cards should use `other_cards.xml` layout and it should be positioned horizontally (see picture below (picture taken from official google site)). [image]

Here's my code

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    private List<CardData> mItems;
    private Context context;
    private SendInfoToCards cardDatas;
    private boolean mainMenu;
    private static final int FIRST = 1;
    private static final int SECOND = 2;

    public CardAdapter(Context c, SendInfoToCards datas, boolean main) {
        super();
        this.context = c;
        this.cardDatas = datas;
        mItems = datas.getList();
        this.mainMenu = main;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {
        if(!mainMenu) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_card_item, viewGroup, false);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
            v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    TextView city = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_movie);
                    String fragmentSwitcher = city.getText().toString();
                    if (fragmentSwitcher.equals("Zemelapis")) {
                        switchFragments(0);
                    } else {
                        switchFragments(1);
                    }
                }
            });
            return viewHolder;
        } else {
            View v;
            if(position == 0){
                v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.first_layout, viewGroup, false);
            }else{
                v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.second_layout, viewGroup, false);
            }
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
            v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    TextView city = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_movie);
                    String fragmentSwitcher = city.getText().toString();
                }
            });
            return viewHolder;
        }
    }

    private void switchFragments(int nr){
        if(nr == 0){
            Log.d("TAG", "mapo");
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailTourActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        if(i != 0){

        } else {
            CardData data = mItems.get(i);
            viewHolder.tvMovie.setText(data.getName());
            viewHolder.imgThumbnail.setImageResource(data.getThumbnail());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public ImageView imgThumbnail;
        public TextView tvMovie;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imgThumbnail = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail);
            tvMovie = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_movie);
        }
    }
}
```

Sadly but `onCreateViewHolder` method second argument `position` is always 0. Why is that? How to fix it?

Comment: Overriding getItemViewType(int position) fixed the issue:

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what your adapter class should roughly look like

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecylerView.ViewHolder>{
    private List<CardData> mItems;
    private Context context;
    private SendInfoToCards cardDatas;
    private boolean mainMenu;
    private static final int FIRST = 1;
    private static final int SECOND = 2;

    public CardAdapter(Context c, SendInfoToCards datas, boolean main) {
        super();
        this.context = c;
        this.cardDatas = datas;
        mItems = datas.getList();
        this.mainMenu = main;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int type) {
        if(type == SECOND){
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.second_layout, viewGroup, false);
            return new SecondViewViewHolder(v);
        } else {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.first_layout, viewGroup, false);
            return new FirstViewViewHolder(v);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        if(viewHolder instanceof SecondViewViewHolder){
            SecondViewViewHolder secondViewViewHolder = (SecondViewViewHolder) viewHolder;
            // bind second views
            secondViewViewHolder.imgThumbnail.setImageResource(R.id.img_resource);
        } else {
            FirstViewViewHolder firstViewViewHolder = (FirstViewViewHolder) viewHolder;
            // bind firs view
            firstViewViewHolder.imgThumbnail.setImageResource(R.id.img_resource);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return FIRST;
        } else {
            return SECOND;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    class FirstViewViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public ImageView imgThumbnail;
        public TextView tvMovie;

        public FirstViewViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imgThumbnail = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail);
            tvMovie = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_movie);
        }
    }

    class SecondViewViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public ImageView imgThumbnail;
        public TextView tvMovie;
        public ImageView imgThumbnail2;
        public TextView tvMovie2;

        public SecondViewViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            //find viewby id
        }
    }
}
```

**What is changed**

Since recyclerview can handle multiple view types you can decide which layout to inflate depending on some condition. You do this by overriding **getItemViewTypeMethod()** of the RecylerView Adapter

```
 @Override
 public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
         return FIRST;
    } else {
       return SECOND;
    }
}
```

When creating viewholder. the onCreateViewHolder method will get the view type. Based on the type you should inflate the appropriate layout and return the appropriate viewholder

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int type) {
   if(type == SECOND){
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.second_layout, viewGroup, false);
        return new SecondViewViewHolder(v);
    } else {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.first_layout, viewGroup, false);
        return new FirstViewViewHolder(v);
    }
}
```

Since there are two layouts involved, I have created two View Holders to hold first and second layouts. (FirstViewHolder & SecondViewHolder). Because of this you have to set your adapter's ViewHolder type to the base ViewHolder class like this

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecylerView.ViewHolder>{
   ...
}
```

and now in the onBindViewHolder method, you can determine which ViewHolder is currently being bound and do your work accordingly

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    if(viewHolder instanceof SecondViewViewHolder){
        SecondViewViewHolder secondViewViewHolder = (SecondViewViewHolder) viewHolder;
        // bind second views
            secondViewViewHolder.imgThumbnail.setImageResource(R.id.img_resource);
    } else {
        FirstViewViewHolder firstViewViewHolder = (FirstViewViewHolder) viewHolder;
        // bind firs view
        firstViewViewHolder.imgThumbnail.setImageResource(R.id.img_resource);
    }
}
```

Check [this](http://deepakbaliga.com/index.php/2015/07/17/recyclerview-with-multiple-view-types/) for an example

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that the second parameter is not position, it is `viewType`.

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onCreateViewHolder(android.view.ViewGroup,%20int)):

```
public abstract VH onCreateViewHolder (ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
```

Look at `public void onBindViewHolder (VH holder, int position, List<Object> payloads)`, this is what you actually need

Comment: Thanks, but how `onBindViewHolder` I can inflate the view?

Comment: @David, inflate in onCreateViewHolder, display data in onBindViewHolder. [tutorial](http://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview/)

Comment: but I need to inflate both first and second layout in `onCreateViewHolder`. This tutorial have no info about element position in list. I understand that in `onBindViewHolder` based on position I can display whatever I want, but how to display info on correct layout?

Comment: @David, checkout [this](http://arjunu.com/2015/10/android-recyclerview-with-different-cardviews/)